# Overwriting Core Data information using NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to edit an entry in a Core Data entry using NSPredicate, but I'm not entirely sure as to how it works.

I'm trying to get an entity based on an id from another object, but I can't see where i'm going wrong. Here's my data model in effect:
Entity: myEntity, Attributes: name, id, value.

I'm trying to retrieve the correct object in the Database via this:

```
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"myEntity" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@", self.itemToEdit.ID];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error;

    MyEntity *myEntity = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] objectAtIndex: 0];
    myEntity.value = self.itemToEdit.anotherValue;

    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

For whatever reason, the data is not being saved, the app isn't crashing either which leads me to believe the issue is with the predicate. Anyway, what's wrong with the code? As a note, itemToEdit is not of type myEntity, it is another object, but the assignment types are the same.

Regards, 
Mike

Comment: Have you checked that `id` in your predicate is of the correct case? I see that on your `itemToEdit` object you have a capitalised `ID` property. Also, check your `error` object to see if there are any problems when calling `executeFetchRequest:error:` or `save:`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Error is null for both. Also, double checked the case and it's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case closed guys. Stupid mistake by me. I was so focussed on making this new part of Core Data work (which I find daunting as it is), that I actually forgot to assign self.itemToEdit.value. Sorry for wasting your time.

Mike

Comment: glad it's fixed.  i was just retyping the whole method with nslogs everywhere, including before and after the assignment.  you can mark you're own answer correct.  (it might still be helpful to someone to debug their own problem).

Comment: Thanks danh, sorry for wasting your time.